# Laravel whereHas to realted model, and whereHas to that related modal not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Im having three table:

**Deal Model:**

```
class Deal extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function hotel() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel');
    }
}
```

**Hotel Model:**

```
class Hotel extends Model
{
    public function room(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Room');
    }

    public function deal(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deal');
    }
}
```

**Room Model:**

```
class Room extends Model
{

    public function hotel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel');
    }

}
```

The below query works fine,

```
return $greatDeals = Deal::whereHas('hotel', function ($query) {
                $query->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
            })->get();
```

but i want to query the 'hotel' model wherehas 'room' model
but the below query shows error, was this query format is correct?

```
 return $greatDeals = Deal::whereHas('hotel', function ($query) {
                    $query->whereHas('room', function ($query) {
                        $query->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
                    })->get();
                })->get();
```

The error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deals.hotel_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `hotels` where `deals`.`hotel_id` = `hotels`.`id` and exists (select * from `rooms` where `hotels`.`id` = `rooms`.`hotel_id` and `astatus` = 1 and `status` = 0)) ◀"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the first `get()`:

```
Deal::whereHas('hotel', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('room', function ($query) {
            $query->where('astatus', 1)->where('status', 0);
        });
    })->get();
```

Or do this:

```
Deal::whereHas('hotel.room', function ($query) {
        $query->where('astatus', 1)->where('status', 0);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Both are working fine, im taking first one because i need to add the same where condition ($query->where('astatus', 1)->where('status', 0);) for hotel also.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin. You are everywhere , :)